# Надо синонимизировать метки [информатика] и [computer-science]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки

- [информатика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) (80 вопросов)
- [computer-science](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) (26 вопросов)

- они [очень похожи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1536097/507426), и их надо синонимизировать.

Comment: Вообще да. Это одно и тоже, просто одно на англйиском, другое на русском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 29 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 26 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 25 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'computer-science': [computer-science] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 105
tag remapping of [информатика] and [computer-science] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym computer-science -> информатика was approved!
```